# Context processors and model objects. Django

Tags: django

The question is simple.

In each of my views I need to have the following code:

```
def my_view(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    # Some code...
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p
            # The rest of the dict...
        })
```

So I think It's an appropriate situation to use `context processors`.

But I don't understand how to give the `poll_id` argument to my context processor func.

Every suggestion will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an appropriate use of context processors. You might find that generic views are a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

You have better to use `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

#### a sample TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

add a file say `custom_processors.py` to any of your app with these codes:

```
def my_view(request):
    p = Poll.objects.filter(pk=1)
    # Some code...
    return {'poll':p[0] if p else '',}
```

add it to `settings.py` `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` like:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS=(
    ...
    '<appname>.custom_processors.my_view',
)
```

if there isn't any `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable in `settings.py` then import and append it:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('<appname>.custom_processors.my_view',)
```

Now you can use `{{poll}}` in any of your template.

Answer (score 1):

Since context processors are run "globally" (you don't call them directly, but they're run automatically after your view has been processed), i don't think there's an easy way to do what you want.

Why not use a helper function in your views ? Something along the lines of

```
def get_poll(context, poll_pk):
    context['poll'] = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_pk)
```

and then in your view:

```
def my_view(request):
    conext = {}
    # Some code...
    get_poll(context, your_poll_id)
    return render(...)
```

Or, depending on your url patterns, you could probably parse the `request.path` attribute in your context processor to figure out the id you want, but this seems hackish and will break if you change you url design.